# Create specific json response from linq to SQL query output?

Tags: c#, json, list, webapi

I am working on Web API. I am getting data from one database table:

```
DispatchData dta = new DispatchData();

using (SalesDataContext oSqlData4 = new SalesDataContext())
{
    var result = (from x in oSqlData4.Finances
                  where (x.records.ID.Equals("12") ||
                         x.records.ID.Equals("123"))
                  where (x.Status == "Not Approved")
                  select x).ToList();

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        dta.data = new string[] { item.Order_ID.ToString(), item.ID.ToString() };
    }

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dta);
        
    return json;
}

public class DispatchData
{
    public string[] data;
}
```

This code is returning only one record:

```
{ "data": ["2508", "4684"] }
```

I want each row in array like this

```
{"data":[ ["2508","4684"],["2223","1123"],....] }
```

Comment: Issue is in this line `data.data = …` you are always assigning to array. You need to add this to array

Answer (score 0):

Why not make return the `result` as strongly typed Model of `List<DispatchData>`:

Your `DispatchData` class:

```
public class DispatchData
{
    public string Order_ID {get;set;}
    public string ID {get;set;}
}
```

You can create a `Root` class to handle your `JSON`:

```
public class Root
{
  public List<DispatchData> data=new List<DispatchData>();
}
```

And you can return from your query like this:

```
Root dta = new Root();
using (SalesDataContext oSqlData4 = new SalesDataContext())
{
    dta.data = (from x in oSqlData4.Finances
                  where (x.records.ID.Equals("12") ||
                         x.records.ID.Equals("123"))
                  where (x.Status == "Not Approved")
                  select x).ToList();

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dta);
        
    return json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the result you want, your class is defined wrongly

```cs
public class DispatchData
{
    public string[][] data;
}
```

Then you can directly select the pair of IDs in an array, then nest them in another array, and assign it directly to `dta.data`

```cs
using (SalesDataContext oSqlData4 = new SalesDataContext())
{
    var dta = new DispatchData() {
        data = (from x in oSqlData4.Finances
                  where (x.records.ID.Equals("12") ||
                         x.records.ID.Equals("123"))
                  where (x.Status == "Not Approved")
                  select new[]{ x.Order_ID.ToString(), item.ID.ToString() }
               ).ToArray()
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dta);
        
    return json;
}
```